# Scrolling via SmartWatch control

Tags: java, scroll, sony, sony-smartwatch

I very much like the look and feel of Sony's extensions for the SmartWatch that have the scrolling functionality, and I would like to have the same thing in my apps. Is there any example or guideline how to implement this?

It would be nice if such functionality were a part of the Utils lib, as I see no need to waste time and brainpower to implement something that every programmer today takes for granted. I would rather focus on some unique features I'd like to develop.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean the nice default transitions?  left right up down?  I would realy like those as well.  Have done my own system but it's far from smooth, you just can't get the transfer rate to be smooth.

Comment: @Ifor, yes exactly that. I don't see why we should spend time and efforts implementing such standard functionality, instead of focus on innovative work.

Comment: Agree totaly and asked my contact with Sony 3 months back but no joy hence my own not very good homemade solution.  The scrolling is clearly being do on the watch e.g. give it 2 screens and tell it to animate but there are no api to access this for us developers.

Comment: I have seen your solution, and while I find it very effective (though a bit slow), I want something else: a list which can be scrolled by touch, i.e. up and down as needed. I will eventually find my way through the logic, but I see no point of wasting time for such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not possible with the SmartWatch 1, but can be achieved through lists and galleries in SmartWatch 2. That is the only way, so far.

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling functionality that you refer to is implemented in the firmware of the SmartWatch, and is only applicable for the Notification extensions. Due to limitations of the watch hardware, this cannot currently be applied to the Control extensions.

Comment: Hope that the API will be extended in the future, and allow for scrolling in the Control extensions.

Comment: Does this also apply to SmartWatch 2? bought that toy with plans to build something but now I know why there are not even 300 apps for that yet.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I've found I can simulate scrollable text by rendering the text into a bitmap in memory, and then displaying a list of bitmaps, each of which is a chunk extracted from the bitmap.

http://damianblog.com/2014/01/12/sw2-scrollable-text/

Comment: Yes, but it's not smooth, as you cannot make sufficiently frequent screen refreshes via the API. That is also what Ifor implemented earlier, and spoke of it in the above comments. Thanks for your input anyway!